# Submit to app store phonegap app icon issue

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode6, phonegap-build, appstore-approval

I have developed a phonegap application which is running absolutely fine on iPhone. Now, I want to submit the app to the appstore. Following is the procedure I am following to submit my app:

1. Open Xcode and archive the project
2. Click on validate (which is successful)
3. Click on Submit to appstore (which is where I am getting the following error[image])

Not sure, where I am going wrong. And I have written the following in config.xml and all the icons of perfect dimensions are there in the icons folder including icon.png of 57x57 dimension:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/AppIcon57x57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/AppIcon29x29.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="Resources/icons/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the images were interlaced and so the error. Make sure the png files that you upload are NOT INTERLACED.

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had got this one before. I resloved this by: Opening  images.xcassets folder in Xcode, tapping on AppIcon and then manually dragging and dropping the respective app icons in each field. Luckily I had comps for all fields and I was able to solve it. Hope this information help.

Comment: What do you mean by comps ? Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: Well, that is a term we use at office. It means components, which includes the actual UI(user interface) elements that we use in the app. The art director (the Person who made the app icons) provided me with all the app icons of different pixels as required in Xcode. You can use a Mac application called "prepo" to create app icons of different size and pixels. Hope this helps.